# Opening a solution with msbuildworkspace gives diagnostics errors without details

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to analyse a solution with Roslyn, with MSBuildWorkspace.
The solution is a new solution, with 2 class library projects in them, one referencing the other.

They are created in Visual Studio 2017, .Net 4.6.2.

When I open the solution, I receive two generic errors in workspace.Diagnostics, both are :
Msbuild failed when processing the file '*PathToProject*'
There is nothing more in the diagnostics or output window, to indicate WHY it failed to process the project file.

The code for opening the solution:

```
namespace RoslynAnalyse
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LocalAnalysis();
        }

        private static void LocalAnalysis()
        {
            var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
            var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(@"D:\Code\Roslyn\RoslynAnalyse\SolutionToAnalyse\SolutionToAnalyse.sln").Result;
            var workspaceDiagnostics = workspace.Diagnostics;

        }
    }
}
```

The version of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis is 2.0.0.0.
Does anybody have any idea why MSBuild failed, how I can get more information ?

Comment: Best to file a bug at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn if you haven't already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When MSBuildWorkspace fails to open a project or solution this way, it is almost always because the application using MSBuildWorkspace does not include the same binding redirects that msbuild.exe.config has in it.

MSBuild uses binding redirects to allow tasks (typically already compiled C# code using possibly different versions of msbuild API libraries) to all use the current msbuild API's. Otherwise, msbuild gets runtime load failures.

The solution is to add an app.config file to your project and copy the binding redirects (the assemblyBinding section of the msbuild.exe.config file) into your file.

Comment: been trying to find a solution for this issue for weeks now. Although I've come across your answer before, I misread it and made an error, using a different version as was in the msbuild.exe.config file. Just copied the rebindings into my own app.config and the diagnostic errors are all gone. You are my champ for the day :-D

Comment: @Matt Warren's answer works great for me. One addition: there could be quite few versions of MsBuild, with various "bindingRedirect" elements. Be carefull when select your one. 
In my case C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe.config was correct.