# Error using the MSBuild.CodeAnalysis apis to analyze a C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, roslyn-code-analysis

I am attempting to build a tool (using C# and .NET 7.0, Visual Studio 2022) that will analyze another C# project.  I added the `MSBuild.Locator` package and invoked it with `MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults()`.  However, when I attempt to actually open the project to be analyzed, I get the following error:

[image: Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Microsoft.Build.resources.dll'. The system cannot find the file specified.']

Here is the source code of the tool:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Locator;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace AnalysisTool
{
   class Program
   {
      public static async Task DoActualWork()
      {
         var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
         workspace.LoadMetadataForReferencedProjects = true;
         workspace.WorkspaceFailed += OnWorkspaceFailed;

         // Error occurs here
         var project = await workspace.OpenProjectAsync(
            @"C:\Path\To\OtherProject.csproj");

         var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
      }

      public static async Task Main(string[] args)
      {
         var vsAvail = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().ToList();

         MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();

         await DoActualWork();
      }

      private static void OnWorkspaceFailed(object sender,Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.WorkspaceDiagnosticEventArgs e)
      {
         if (e.Diagnostic.Kind == Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.WorkspaceDiagnosticKind.Failure)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Diagnostic.ToString());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And the analysis tool's associated project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <RollForward>Major</RollForward>
    <OutDir>..\Bin\</OutDir>
    <OutputPath>$(OutDir)</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.5.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Features" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.ProjectModel" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I've tried walking it back to .NET 5.0, with the same error.  I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45948110/8772744

Answer (score -1):

On the associated project file...
Add this

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="7.0.0" />
```

your new csproj file will be like;

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <RollForward>Major</RollForward>
    <OutDir>..\Bin\</OutDir>
    <OutputPath>$(OutDir)</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.5.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Features" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.ProjectModel" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).